# how to cache object using pickle in __new__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, pickle

I'd like to cache an object in `__new__` method so that it can load the cache when a new object is constructed, but now the following code will got an exception:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I have no idea about how to break the recursion

```
import pickle

class Cache:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}

    def __setitem__(self, obj, val):
        self.d[obj] = pickle.dumps(val)

    def __getitem__(self, obj):
        return pickle.loads(self.d[obj])

class Car:

    cache = Cache()

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self.__class__, (self.name,))

    def __new__(cls, name):
        try:
            return cls.cache[name]
        except KeyError:
            return cls.new(name)

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, name):
        car = object.__new__(cls)
        car.init(name)
        cls.cache[name] = car
        return car

    def init(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


a = Car('audi')
b = Car('audi')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try. This may fix this, but it may not be the proper solution. If anyone have any better idea, feel free to leave comments.

Just remove the `__reduce__` method.

Then implement `__getnewargs__` and `__getnewargs_ex__`

```py
import pickle

class Cache:
  def __init__(self):
    self.d = {}

  def __setitem__(self, obj, val):
    self.d[obj] = pickle.dumps(val)

  def __getitem__(self, obj):
    return pickle.loads(self.d[obj])

  def __contains__(self, x):
    return x in self.d

class Car:
  cache = Cache()

  def __new__(cls, name, extra=None, _FORCE_CREATE=False):
    if _FORCE_CREATE or name not in cls.cache:
      car = object.__new__(cls)
      car.init(name)
      car.extra = extra
      cls.cache[name] = car
      return car
    else:
      return cls.cache[name]

  def init(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.name

  def __getnewargs__(self):
    return (self.name, None, True)

  def __getnewargs_ex__(self):
    # override __getnewargs_ex__ and __getnewargs__ to provide args for __new__
    return (self.name, ), {"_FORCE_CREATE": True}

a = Car('audi', extra="extra_attr")
b = Car('audi')

print(id(a), a.extra) # 1921399938016 extra_attr
print(id(b), b.extra) # 1921399937728 extra_attr
```

Comment: Is there any other method that do not change the __new__ method ?